# Python: How to read a CSV file in which each line is a string?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file. I need to access the keys and values in each line.

```
"{id:495981,start:""2020-09-23"",end:""2020-09-23"",something:point({srid:4326, x:10.96791704, y:49.7989944})}"
"{id:49963,start:""2020-09-23"",end:""2020-09-23"",something:point({srid:4326, x:10.96791704, y:49.7989944})}"
```

As shown above, each line is a string. What I want to do is reading the value of id in each line. Reading the file with "panda.read_csv" return something like this:

```
  {id:495981   end:""2020-09-23""  start:""2020-09-23""  \
    0      {id:49963   end:""2020-09-23""  start:""2020-09-23""  
           ...
    something:point({srid:4326         x:7.138        y:51.594})}  
    0      something:point({srid:4326   x:10.96791704    y:49.7989944})}
[31264 rows x 6 columns]
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: How are you wishing to store the `id` and values?

Comment: As ["key":"value"]

Comment: As a dictonary?

Comment: Yes as dictionary

Comment: you want id's only? If yes what will the dictionary include (as keys:values) except from id's? Can you provide a sample of the expected output?

Comment: The root of all your problems really is that your file format is horrible. Is there any chance to change the producer of this information to just produce a standard format like JSON (or XML, or YAML, or what have you) instead?

Comment: @tripleee is correct, this is complicated by the input data being way over complicated for what it is. The answer I provided will work, but your best solution is to adjust the input file instead.

Comment: @archer  Yes. Based on the value of id, I can access a server that provides information on temperature, P1, P2. I will add them to the dictionary.

Comment: Looks like somene printed key:values in a json-like fashion, then copy-pasted this to excel and saved to csv. I would 'convert' ir to JSON with1) strip('"') on every line, 2) translate('""',""') double quotes to single quotes, then 3) Find with a regex ([^{\s,:{]+): the text before the ':' and add quotes. Not an easy task to do json.loads with the result line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize `regex` here to pull each result out of the string as splitting would include the extra characters I'm assuming you would want to exclude.

```
import re

data = {}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line_id = re.search('(?<=id:)[0-9]*(?=,)', line).group(0)
        line_data = {'start': re.search('(?<=start:"").*(?="",end)', line).group(0),
                     'end': re.search('(?<=end:"").*(?="",something)', line).group(0),
                     'something': re.search('(?<=something:).*(?=}")', line).group(0),
                     }
        data[line_id] = line_data

print(data)
```

This will result in a `dict` with all `ids` as a key with each key containing another `dict` with all the values in the string.

```
{'495981': {'start': '2020-09-23', 'end': '2020-09-23', 'something': 'point({srid:4326, x:10.96791704, y:49.7989944})'}, 
'49963': {'start': '2020-09-23', 'end': '2020-09-23', 'something': 'point({srid:4326, x:10.96791704, y:49.7989944})'}}
```